# Recieve notifications of Magento 2 updates for multiple websites

Tags: magento, version, updates

So here is my problem, I have several Magento 1 sites, all of which are running on different versions. When a new version of Magento 1 is released, I want to be able to have a notification that tells me each of my sites current versions and if there is a new update available.

I don't have much experience at all of web scraping, rss feeds or even recieving an email with these notifications but I'm pretty sure my answer would come from one of these.

I have asked this question on stackoverflow Magento as well but I did not get a suitable answer. [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249429/anyway-of-being-notified-of-a-magento-2-update-without-logging-in-the-admin-pane)

Answer (score 0):

normally magento will notified when release verison in admin portal.

Comment: I don't want to rely on the admin panel as I do not always logon to my sites for months

Comment: so which channel did you want to receive notification

Comment: Any really, whatever is easiest. Just was wondering if it was easy to set up an rss feed or maybe a master email that lets me know when there is a new update.

Answer (score 0):

The notifications in admin are stored in the database table `adminnotification_inbox`. My approach would be to setup a cron job that checks for entries containing `https://www.devdocs/magento.com/...` in the url column and trigger a custom mail if entries are found.